# Correct usage of addAttributeToFilter in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm having issues filtering a product collection with a customer attribute using 'addAttributeToFilter.' I have a dropdown menu attribute with the options 'yes' and 'no' and I'd like to to show only a list of products with the attribute set to 'yes.' I'm currently using:

`public function getReleasesCollection()
    {

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('preorder', array ('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('releasedate');`

However this does not return any products.

I have also tried using:

`->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 1);`

`->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', '1');`

`->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 'Yes);`

`->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => '1'));`

`->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 'Yes'));`

I am able to filter by any other attribute such as name, sku, description, etc. but I'm unable to filter with my custom attribute.

Any pointers?

Comment: I've come up with a solution but I'm not 100% sure this is the best way to do this.

Comment: If it works at all, it's probably worth mentioning.

Comment: I've uploaded my code to github in case anyone might find it useful. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5724967

Comment: When in doubt, I'd always recommend ->addFieldToFilter(). Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/262983/

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php 

class LSC_ReleaseCalendar_Block_Calendar extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
{    
    public function getReleasesCollection()
  { 
        $preorderAttribute = 'preorder';
        $preorderValue = 'yes';
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()  
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                $preorderAttribute,
                    array(
                        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getAttribute($preorderAttribute)
                            ->getSource()
                            ->getOptionId($preorderValue)
                )
            );
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            echo $product->getName();
            echo $product->getReleaseDate();
        }
    }

}
```

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5724967)